# CodeMirror Doesn't Display HTML Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codemirror

I am trying to use CodeMirror modes in my web application, but it won't highlight the words for the mode "htmlmixed". I don't understand what is going wrong. The paths to each file are correct because I am not getting any 404 errors. Here is what I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>           
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path-to/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
   <script src="/path-to/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
   <script src="/path-to/codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
   <script src="/path-to/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
    <textarea id="editor"></textarea>
    ....
</html>
<script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
         lineNumbers: true,
         mode:  "htmlmixed",
         htmlMode: true,
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path-to/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">` Is this an actual path?

Comment: Hi ksav, I just revised the path for simplicity here. The path in my actual code is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `htmlmixed` mode depends on the `xml`, `javascript`, and `css` modes. They must be included for `htmlmixed` to work.

Here is an example:

```js
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  mode:  "htmlmixed",
  htmlMode: true,
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.41.0/codemirror.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.41.0/codemirror.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.41.0/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.41.0/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.41.0/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.41.0/mode/css/css.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
  <textarea id="editor">&lt;p&gt; I am HTML&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;script&gt;
  console.log(&quot;I am JS&quot;);
&lt;/script&gt;</textarea>
</html>
```

Comment: also, same code for mode `javascript` for json coloring mode: javascript